# How to execute Common Lisp code from Python

Tags: python, common-lisp

I would like to execute a Common Lisp (SBCL) code from Python e.g. via shell. Also I need to run a Lisp-library called Shop3 to execute my Lisp code. I tried:

```
os.system('sbcl && (asdf:load-system "shop3") && (in-package:SHOP-USER) && (load "/Users/kiliankramer/Desktop/Shop-Planer/planner-new")')
```

But it's not working, it's only starting sbcl but then stop before to load the asdf library "shop3".

Can you tell how to execute my Lisp code or what alternatives I have to run an external Lisp program (including the Lisp library) to execute it?

Thanks in forward. :)

Comment: The file I am trying to execute from python is "load "/Users/kiliankramer/Desktop/Shop-Planer/planner-new" but for that I need to load shop3 before.

Comment: I'm not familiar with shop. Can it be executed in hylang (https://github.com/hylang/hy)?

Comment: thanks, I read about Hy, I will try that! :) (ps: SHOP3 - Simple Hierarchical Order Planner is a planner for robotics)

Comment: SHOP3 is a system for planning tasks and is written in Common Lisp: https://github.com/shop-planner/shop3

Comment: See also cl4py, it's supposed to help in this scenario: https://github.com/marcoheisig/cl4py/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`&&` chains shell commands. I.e., it starts `sbcl` and waits for it to terminate, and if the termination was successful, then it will try to execute `(asdf:load-system "shop3")` as a *shell command* (not what you want!)

You need to use [sbcl command line arguments](https://lispcookbook.github.io/cl-cookbook/scripting.html):

```py
os.system("sbcl --eval '(asdf:load-system \\"shop3\\")' --eval '(in-package :SHOP-USER)' --load /Users/kiliankramer/Desktop/Shop-Planer/planner-new")
```

However, you might want to use [the more modern interface](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html) instead of [`os.system`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.system).
It will also avoid the need for escaping quotes &c:

```py
subprocess.run(["sbcl","--eval",'(asdf:load-system "shop3")',
                "--eval",'(in-package :SHOP-USER)',
                "--load","/Users/kiliankramer/Desktop/Shop-Planer/planner-new")
```